# Excel Index Match and Date Array Formula returns same value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get all dates from the first column for which the number 1 is displayed in the next column, using INDEX MATCH and an Array formula.

I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong, the dates returned repeat themselves a number of times. I want only each individual date once.

Formula:

```
{=INDEX(D1:E7, MATCH(1,E1:E7,0), 1)}

D1:E7 contain from 01.01.2022 to 01.07.2022

E1:E7 contain 0,1,0,1,1,0,1
```

Result :

```
02.02.2022
02.02.2022
04.02.2022
04.02.2022
05.02.2022
07.02.2022
07.02.2022
```

Expected result :

```
02.02.2022
04.02.2022
05.02.2022
07.02.2022
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove duplicated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Answer is related to Excel versions older than 2021.** If you are using recent Excel version, see the other answer which provide much more easier formula.

You get this result because you don't have locked ranges `D1:D7` and `E1:E7`.

Here you see your result and formula which produces them

```
02.01.2022  {=INDEX(D1:D7,MATCH(1,E1:E7,0),1)}
02.01.2022  {=INDEX(D2:D8,MATCH(1,E2:E8,0),1)}
04.01.2022  {=INDEX(D3:D9,MATCH(1,E3:E9,0),1)}
04.01.2022  {=INDEX(D4:D10,MATCH(1,E4:E10,0),1)}
05.01.2022  {=INDEX(D5:D11,MATCH(1,E5:E11,0),1)}
07.01.2022  {=INDEX(D6:D12,MATCH(1,E6:E12,0),1)}
07.01.2022  {=INDEX(D7:D13,MATCH(1,E7:E13,0),1)}
```

Use [Evaluate formula tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to see each step of calculation

I suppose, you are using older version of Excel (because you are still using array formulas). So we have to omit new useful formulas as `SORT` or `UNIQUE`.

### Use this Array formula and stretch it down

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$7,SMALL($E$1:$E$7*ROW($E$1:$E$7),ROWS($D$1:$D$7)-SUM($E$1:$E$7)+ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1)+1)),"")}
```

### How it works:

1. `$E$1:$E$7*ROW($E$1:$E$7)` returns an array with row numbers of where is 1 in range `E1:E7` and zeroes. In our case: `0,2,0,4,5,0,7`
2. Then we use `SMALL`  function for array from `1.` to get only values higher than zero. You can imagine that `SMALL` sort the input array and return value on given position. In our case is the sorted array `0,0,0,2,4,5,7`
3. Now we want skip leading zeroes. It's done by `ROWS($D$1:$D$7)-SUM($E$1:$E$7)`which returns in our case `7-4=3`
4. And we want to get item by item from `SMALL`, so we need some sequence (+1) for each next row. Its done by `ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1)`. If you stretch it down it gives sequence `0,1,2...`
5. Getting `2-4` together we get `ROWS($D$1:$D$7)-SUM($E$1:$E$7)+ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1)+1)` which represents position of wanted item in `SMALL` sorted array (see `1`)
6. Now we have formula which stretched down returns row numbers for rows where is 1 in `E:E7` `SMALL($E$1:$E$7*ROW($E$1:$E$7),ROWS($D$1:$D$7)-SUM($E$1:$E$7)+ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1)+1)`
7. So we can use this formula from `6` in `INDEX` function. `INDEX($D$1:$D$7,SMALL($E$1:$E$7*ROW($E$1:$E$7),ROWS($D$1:$D$7)-SUM($E$1:$E$7)+ROW(D1)-ROW($D$1)+1))`
8. If you try to stretch formula from `7` to more rows than is `1` values in `E1:E7`, you get an error there. This is solved by `IFERROR` function which returns empty text `""` if there is an error.

**PS:** If your data in columns D and E are not starting in 1st row, you need to adjust the formula. But I'm sure, you know how by now.

Comment: You're right, when I did the sample code I forgot to lock the ranges. The initial issue was that it returned the same first row. But with your code sample above, this works like a charm. Thank you very much for the whole explanation !

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent version of Excel, you can use `FILTER`, like this:

[image]

Formula in G2:

```
=FILTER($D$1:$D$7,$E$1:$E$7=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will update my Excel version soon. This is quite a useful function !